# Compact Metric Space is Separable

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

My attempt:

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Then $X$ is totally bounded $\implies$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there are finitely many points $x_1,...x_{m_n}\in X$ such that $X\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^mB_{1/n}(x_i)$. Let $C_n=\{x_1,...,x_{m_n}\}$. Then $C=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C_n$ is countable. To show it is dense in $X$, let $y\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$ both be arbitrary. Take $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. Then since $\{B_{1/N}(x_1),...,B_{1/N}(x_{m_N})\}$ is an open cover for $X$, $y\in B_{1/N}(x_i)$ for some $i\in\{1,...,m_N\}$. But then $d(y,x_i)=d(x_i,y)<1/N<\epsilon$, so $x_i\in B_{\epsilon}\cap C$. Hence, $C$ is dense in $X$.

Does anyone see any problems with this argument? Thanks

Comment: Your proof looks okay to me. However, you also may proceed like this: compact spaces are Lindelöf, and Lindelöf is equivalent to separability in metric spaces.

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba If he already knew about Lindelöfness being equivalent  to separability, he wouldn't have asked this question. The proof for Lindelöfness is the same, only you use that a countable union of countable sets (instead of finite sets) is countable , which comes down to the same thing.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I didn't express myself clearly, sorry. I'm not assuming he knows these facts, but instead he could prove these facts with the same proof, breaking his original result in two (slightly more general) others results. Once again, I am sorry.